# How to handle before filter for specific action in Grape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape, grape-api

I'm mounting Grape in my Rails project to build a RESTful API.

Now some end-points have actions need authentication and others which don't need authentication.

As for example I have `users` end-point which looks something like:

```
module Backend
  module V1
    class Users < Grape::API
      include Backend::V1::Defaults

      before { authenticate! }

      resource :users do

        desc "Return a user"
        params do
          requires :id, type: Integer, desc: 'User id'
        end
        get ':id' do
          UsersService::Fetch.new(current_user,params).call
        end

        desc "Update a user"
        params do
          requires :id, type: Integer, desc: 'User id'
          requires :display_name, type: String, desc: 'Display name'
          requires :email, type: String, desc: 'Email'
        end
        post ':id' do
          UsersService::Save.new(current_user,params).call
        end

        desc "Reset user password"
        params do
          requires :old_password, type: String, desc: 'old password'
          requires :password, type: String, desc: 'new password'
        end
        post 'password/reset' do
          PasswordService::Reset.new(current_user,params).call
        end

        desc "Forget password"
        params do
          requires :email, type: String
        end
        post 'password/forget' do
          PasswordService::Forget.new(current_user,params).call
        end            

      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now as you can see, all the actions except `password/forget` needs the user to be logged-in/authenticated. It doesn't make sense too to create a new end-point let's say `passwords` and just remove `password/forget` there as logically speaking, this end-point should be related to users resource.

The problem is with Grape `before` filter has no options like `except, only` in which I can say apply the filter for certain actions.

How do you usually handle such a case in a clean way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dirty way to help would be by using `namespace`, something like:

```
module Backend
  module V1
    class Users < Grape::API
      include Backend::V1::Defaults

      namespace :users do
        desc "Forget password"
        params do
          requires :email, type: String
        end
        post 'password/forget' do
          PasswordService::Forget.new(current_user,params).call
        end

        namespace do
          before { authenticate! }

          desc "Return a user"
          params do
            requires :id, type: Integer, desc: 'User id'
          end
          get ':id' do
            UsersService::Fetch.new(current_user,params).call
          end

          desc "Update a user"
          params do
            requires :id, type: Integer, desc: 'User id'
            requires :display_name, type: String, desc: 'Display name'
            requires :email, type: String, desc: 'Email'
          end
          post ':id' do
            UsersService::Save.new(current_user,params).call
          end

          desc "Reset user password"
          params do
            requires :old_password, type: String, desc: 'old password'
            requires :password, type: String, desc: 'new password'
          end
          post 'password/reset' do
            PasswordService::Reset.new(current_user,params).call
          end            

        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This way we wont run before filter for `users/password/forget` but for the rest we will run `before { authenticate! }`

Comment: upvoted.. I wonder if now there's an more elegant way of doing it

Comment: Works only directly in endpoint class. It is not working if you would like to do something like before callback for specific `mount API`. For example I want to run it got `mount Admin::Base` but I don't want it to be run on `Public::Base`

Answer (score 13):

One way I could think of is to use `route_setting` to add custom attributes for the routes you would want to by-pass auth for. Check for these attributes in the before filter before calling `authenticate!`. Something like the below should work:

```
module Backend
  module V1
    class Users < Grape::API
      include Backend::V1::Defaults

      before { authenticate! unless route.settings[:auth] && route.settings[:auth][:disabled] }

      resource :users do

        desc "Return a user"
        params do
          requires :id, type: Integer, desc: 'User id'
        end
        get ':id' do
          UsersService::Fetch.new(current_user,params).call
        end

        desc "Update a user"
        params do
          requires :id, type: Integer, desc: 'User id'
          requires :display_name, type: String, desc: 'Display name'
          requires :email, type: String, desc: 'Email'
        end
        post ':id' do
          UsersService::Save.new(current_user,params).call
        end

        desc "Reset user password"
        params do
          requires :old_password, type: String, desc: 'old password'
          requires :password, type: String, desc: 'new password'
        end
        post 'password/reset' do
          PasswordService::Reset.new(current_user,params).call
        end

        desc "Forget password"
        route_setting :auth, disabled: true
        params do
          requires :email, type: String
        end
        post 'password/forget' do
          PasswordService::Forget.new(current_user,params).call
        end            

      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I like this better than the accepted answer. The namespace approach means that the before action has to live inside the nested namespace. This would allow registering it in the api base and only excluding it on a select few endpoints, potentially in different files.

Comment: `before { authenticate! unless route.settings.dig(:auth, :disabled) }` in that way is a little bit shorter :)

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more clear but maybe not so obvious way will be splitting your namespace into separate subclasses:

```
module API
  module Users
    class Root < Grape::API
      namespace :users do
        mount Create # <= `before` callback is not executed

        before do
          authenticate!
        end

        mount Update # <= `before` callback is executed
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The relative directory structure thus will look something like this:

```
 api/users/root.rb
 api/users/create.rb
 api/users/update.rb
```